# Logout the user when that user deleted in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5.0 and I have a claim and role based authentication. I wanna logout the user when i deleted it. I already try to add to my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    // enables immediate logout, after updating the user's security stamp.
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;   
});
```

and its not working.

I did not use the `UserManager` on the authentication and authorize.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be not taking `Zero` as a value.
Try this:-

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});
```

It's will resolve your issue.

Comment: but everyone is using ```Zero```. im gonna try again

Comment: @BerkGarip https://forums.asp.net/t/2154720.aspx?ASP+Net+MVC+Delete+record+and+Logout+that+User

Comment: i think u did not read my answer well. I'm saying i did not use the ```UserManager``` on the authentication. So its useless for me.

Comment: @BerkGarip You'll have to ```AddIdentity``` first and ```ConfigureApplicationCookie``` after. did you that?

Comment: how to do that  and where ? @PritomSarkar

Comment: @BerkGarip in your startup file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235230/discussion-between-pritom-sarkar-and-berkgarip).